# ID tag created with var for img Jscript html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Could anybody be so kind as to direct myself and the many other NOVICE LEARNERS who come here seeking Appreciative suggestions for a solution such as this problem please?

I have managed to create an array for the src and the image but i cannot find a way to append a ID array to the ID tag of the IMG that is HTML. i.e img id="foo" src = "bar" ect ect. i wish to have a n array for the ID .

I wish to start coding dry , and i have been watching many vids and tutorials and have managed to get this far...

```
<html>
<body>

<var x=0; x<10; x++1>
<img id="0" src="cicons1.png" style="position:absolute;">



<script>

var i=0

function setup() {
document.getElementById([i]).style = ("position:absolute; left:"+[i*100+100]+"px;" )
document.getElementById([i]).src="Cicons"+[i]+".png";

console.log([i])
}
for (var i=0; i<10; i=i+1) { setup();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But i wish to have an array for the ID also so i donnot have to repeat the image tag
 over and over again. as i am dealing with over 60+ icons and images and text captions. so it would be ideal to have a DRY method, And i have failed very badly to provide a solution myself, So now i must turn to the experts..

So i thank you in advance if you have a solution..

https://ibb.co/ifGcKk

Answer (score 0):

Please, be aware there are really a lot of ways to do such a task, here is just an example:

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="iconContainer"></div>
<div id="icoSelected" style="position: absolute; top: 120px;">Selected: -none-</div>
<script>
  function showSelected() {
    document.getElementById('icoSelected').innerHTML = this.src;
  }
  function setup(cnt, id) {
    var imgEl = document.createElement('img');
    var icoName = "Cicons"+id+".png";
    imgEl.id = 'icon-'+id;
    imgEl.style.position = 'absolute';
    imgEl.style.left = (id-1)*100+20+'px';
    imgEl.style.width = '80px';
    imgEl.style.height = '80px';
    imgEl.src = icoName;
    imgEl.addEventListener('click', showSelected);
    cnt.appendChild(imgEl);
  }
  var cont = document.getElementById('iconContainer');
  for (var i=0, nIcons=10; i<nIcons; i++) {
    setup(cont, i+1);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```